# PHP issue with checkbox post

Tags: php

This is probobly a really stupid issue, but I cannot find out what is the issue. I have this form which I am using as a kind of 'settings' thing with checkbox's for the settings. But for some reason (I am unsure whether data is not getting posted or if its an issue with my function) the `$_SESSION` variable never gets any data in it.

Form code:

```
<form action="savesettings.php" method="POST" id="CSform">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <P class="noticeme">Please note that all of your settings are stored via cookies</P>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="setting1" value="unchecked">Disable page visit alert on page load</label>
        </div>  
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="text-centered">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success onclickspin" id="MSSave">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery function (This submits the form):

```
$("#MSSave").click(function(){
    $("#MSSave").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
    $('#MSSave').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#CSform").submit()
});
```

savesettings.php:

```
<?php
    include_once './includes/init.php';

    if (isset($_POST['setting1'])) {
        $_SESSION['startupalert'] = 'off';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['startupalert'] = 'on';
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo $_POST['setting1'];
?>
```

Summary: The variable `$_SESSION['startupalert']` does not get filled with any data.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that init.php only has `session_start();` in it.

This is where the variable `$_SESSION['startupalert']` is used

```
<?php
        if ($_SESSION['startupalert'] === 'off') {
            $_SESSION['visits'] = $_SESSION['visits'] + 1;
            } elseif (empty($_SESSION['firstvisit'])) {
                $_SESSION['firstvisit'] = 'false';
                $_SESSION['visits'] = 2; 
                ?> 
                <script> swal("Welcome", "This is your first time on the site", "info"); </script>
                <?php
            } else { 
                ?>
                <script> swal("Welcome back", "This is your <?php echo suffix($_SESSION['visits']) ?> visit", "info"); </script>
                <?php
                $_SESSION['visits'] = $_SESSION['visits'] + 1;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: call `session_start()` everytime before you use the $_SESSION variable

Comment: you forgot to call `session_start()`

Comment: @MarcB I forgot to mention that init.php starts the session.

Comment: You will never reach this statement; `echo $_POST['setting1'];` due to your `header` redirect.

Comment: @vonUbisch That was just for an attempt at debugging which I forgot to remove.

Comment: @vonUbisch: not true. it's POSSIBLE, depending on how fast the header gets to the client, but highly unlikely. header() is NOT the equivalent of die/exit. it doesn't do anything to the script execution until the client ACTS on the header.

Comment: Where (when) do you check the value of `$_SESSION['startupalert']`?

Comment: @MartenKoetsier I have added it to the original post now.

Comment: I'm not sure on how your app works exactly, but under certain circumstances it is necessary to explicitly write session. You could try to insert `session_write_close();` right before setting the Location header. (this is usually an issue that might occur in e.g. ajax-apps)

Comment: Have you confirmed that `include_once './includes/init.php';` is actually loading the file?  What if you replace it with `if(include_once './includes/init.php';){ ... then complete the script ... };`?

Comment: @Sablefoste I added the 'if' statement and the script is still executing so it must be loading the init.php

Comment: @MartenKoetsier I tried that but I am still having the issue.

Comment: What happens if you `echo $_SESSION['startupalert'];` BEFORE the header redirect?  Note, I used `$_SESSION`, not `$_POST`?

Comment: @Sablefoste Nothing (that I can see) happens.

Comment: Sorry, then disable the header redirect completely, so you can see the output.  If the code is running, it should say either 'off' or 'on'.  Another test to confirm, add an `else { echo "Session variable not set"; }` at the end of your `if`, so you must get one of three output answers.

Comment: The suggestion by @Sablefoste SHOULD generate a 'headers already sent' error! This indicates that the script is not running. Do you still have the if-clause? Is the script running at all? Maybe, for debugging purposes, you could try to NOT redirect but instead let the browser receive the response (and then echo the various parameters in `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`)?

Comment: @Sablefoste I dont know why, but I have removed the header redirect, but I am still getting redirected to the index.php

Comment: Perhaps this is related to your jQuery.  You don't have a success call, or a `e.preventDefault.`  That is where it may be sending your page to follow the original link.  See the example on https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @Sablefoste I removed the jquery and when the form submits without the jquery it seems to work. Thanks a lot for you guy's help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize in the solution from the comments:

Your jQuery needs to stop the form from submitting twice.  So, I recommend something similar to:

```
$("#MSSave").click(function(){
    $("#MSSave").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
    $('#MSSave').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#CSform").submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault;  // this is new to your code
    )};
});
```